# Calculate Euler yaw pitch and roll for a 3d point to face another

Tags: geometry

This may be a really basic question but the typical atan2 method isn't working when I write it in a program.

I need a camera object to face a certain target in 3D space.
I need to calculate the 3 Euler angles (yaw, pitch, roll) for the camera.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: The solution will not be unique since you can always rotate the camera on its axis and still have it pointing at a target. Like choosing portrait vs. landscape in a real camera.

Comment: You're right, but at least the X and Y can be calculated to face the point, if not a proper Z (roll).

Comment: Can you explain exactly how your use of two-argument arctangent is failing? It seems to me that any correction to your algorithm would involve the addition or subtraction of some multiple of $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your diagram, it appears to me that the transformation takes the unit vector $(i_x,i_y,i_z)$ and rotates it to point to $(f_x,f_y,f_z)$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}c_\Psi&s_\Psi&0\\-s_\Psi&c_\Psi&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&c_\theta&-s_\theta\\0&s_\theta&c_\theta\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}c_\phi&-s_\phi&0\\s_\phi&c_\phi&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}i_x\\i_y\\i_z\end{pmatrix}  =
\begin{pmatrix}f_x\\f_y\\f_z\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $c_\phi = \cos(\phi), s_\phi = \sin(\phi)$, etc.

It isn't hard to solve for $\phi,\theta$ and $\Psi$ if you assume that your camera begins by pointing in a convenient direction such as $(i_x,i_y,i_z) = (0,0,1)$.

Comment: Uh, I should add that when writing these things out, I normally have (a) wrong signs and (b) wrong orders of matrix multiplication.